# Mongodb connections not closing in nodejs tests

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I have a suite of cucumber tests and in the `BeforeFeatures` section I create connections to 2 databases on the same server, I have set the pooling to 2 so I can see when I connect 4 connections occur (2 databases with 2 pools).

Then at the end I close the databases like so:

```
var closeDatabase = function(callback) {
    db1.close(function(){
        db2.close(function(){
            console.log("DONE");
            callback();
        });
    });
};
```

Now this is invoked and I see the console output and the process closes so both database connections should be closed. However if I look at the mongodb logs:

```
2016-01-14T11:45:05.813+0000 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=888 port=27017 dbpath=C:\Tools\mongodb\data 64-bit host=SomePC
2016-01-14T11:45:05.818+0000 [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2016-01-14T11:45:05.821+0000 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.7
2016-01-14T11:45:05.822+0000 [initandlisten] git version: a7d57ad27c382de82e9cb93bf983a80fd9ac9899
2016-01-14T11:45:05.826+0000 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2016-01-14T11:45:05.829+0000 [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-01-14T11:45:05.830+0000 [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "C:\Tools\mongodb\data" } }
2016-01-14T11:45:05.846+0000 [initandlisten] journal dir=C:\Tools\mongodb\data\journal
2016-01-14T11:45:05.848+0000 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2016-01-14T11:45:05.871+0000 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2016-01-14T11:45:11.639+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51841 #1 (1 connection now open)
2016-01-14T11:45:11.646+0000 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:51841 (0 connections now open)
2016-01-14T11:45:11.650+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51842 #2 (1 connection now open)
2016-01-14T11:45:11.653+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51843 #3 (2 connections now open)
2016-01-14T11:45:11.659+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51844 #4 (3 connections now open)
2016-01-14T11:45:11.662+0000 [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:51844 (2 connections now open)
2016-01-14T11:45:11.665+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51845 #5 (3 connections now open)
2016-01-14T11:45:11.669+0000 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51846 #6 (4 connections now open)
2016-01-14T11:45:11.689+0000 [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:51845 (3 connections now open)
2016-01-14T11:45:11.689+0000 [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:51846 (3 connections now open)
2016-01-14T11:45:11.690+0000 [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:51842 (3 connections now open)
2016-01-14T11:45:11.690+0000 [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:51843 (3 connections now open)
```

So at the end although the 2 connections have ended it seems to leave 3 of the 4 connections active. This being said if we look at ports it seems to activate 6 ports even though it only has 4 connections.

So is this common? should I be worried or am I doing anything wrong? The whole reason this is an issue is because when I try to use the connections I get the error:

`MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed`

So I am a bit baffled as to why its seemingly over-allocating and bombing out when I attempt to use the connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error is correct, it was closing the connections then using them, due to they way console outputs happen on windows they are not always 100% in the right order. It turned out cucumber was bombing out silently in an area and was having a knock on effect here.